# How can I print origdate with citeyear in biblatex-chicago?

Tags: biblatex

With "options = {cmsdate=on}" textcite and parencite in biblatex-chicago will print only the origdate in the text.  How can I make citeyear do that?  It prints only the date.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{hume1739,
  author       = {David Hume},
  editor       = {David Fate Norton},
  title        = {A Treatise of Human Nature},
  publisher    = {Oxford University Press},
  year         = 2000,
  address      = {Oxford},
  options      = {cmsdate=on},
  origdate     = {1739/1740}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

textcite: \textcite[111]{hume1739}

citeyear: \citeyear[111]{hume1739}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you are looking for a way to force ``\citeyear`` to print ``origdate`` only ? (and nothing if undefined ?)

Comment: To print only origdate if it is defined but to print date if origdate is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\citeyear` is a generic citing command provided by `biblatex` that is **not** modified by `biblatex-chicago` - it literally just prints the `date` field.

To get the behaviour you wanted, you have to modify its definition so that it knowns about `origyear` and the like.

In the code below, I have redefined `\citeyear` so that it checks if `origyear` exists, and prints `origdate` if so, otherwise it prints `date`.

*Side note:* Date fields are a bit special in `biblatex` (see manual 4.2.4.3 ), that's why the syntax is a bit weird. Read there if you want to know more.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{hume1739,
  author       = {David Hume},
  editor       = {David Fate Norton},
  title        = {A Treatise of Human Nature},
  publisher    = {Oxford University Press},
  year         = 2000,
  address      = {Oxford},
  options      = {cmsdate=on},
  origdate     = {1739/1740}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear} %lifted from biblatex.def
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
   {% modified from here
   \iffieldundef{origyear}
       {\printfield{year}}
       {\printorigdate}
   }% to here
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}



\begin{document}

citeyear: \citeyear[111]{hume1739}

cite \cite{hume1739}
textcite: \textcite[111]{hume1739}



\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use `\autocite*{}` instead.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail in this regard? That way your answer would be more helpful to a wider audience.