# Print origdate with biblatex-chicago - for journal articles

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I want to use [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115645/how-can-i-print-origdate-with-citeyear-in-biblatex-chicago) to include the original date of a publication. However the answer seems to work only with `@book` but not `@article`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{hume1739,
  author       = {David Hume},
  editor       = {David Fate Norton},
  title        = {A Treatise of Human Nature},
  publisher    = {Oxford University Press},
  year         = 2000,
  address      = {Oxford},
  options      = {cmsdate=on},
  origdate     = {1739/1740}
}
@article{mori2012uncanny,
    AUTHOR      = {Mori, Masahiro},
    TITLE       = {The Uncanny Valley},
    TRANSLATOR  = {MacDorman, Karl F. and Kageki, Norri},
    JOURNAL     = {IEEE Robotics \& Automation Magazine},
    VOLUME      = {19},
    NUMBER      = {2},
    PAGES       = {98--100},
    ORIGDATE    = {1994},
    OPTIONS     = {cmsdate=on},
    YEAR        = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear} %lifted from biblatex.def
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
   {% modified from here
   \iffieldundef{origyear}
       {\printfield{year}}
       {\printorigdate}
   }% to here
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}

\cite{hume1739}, \cite{mori2012uncanny}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

So the 2012 is missing from Mori:

[image]

I would also ideally have the dates flipped. Like a citation 'Mori 2012' and in the bibliography 'Mori Masahiro. 2012. ... (orig. 1994)'

Comment: You should note that `\citeyear` (as defined above) is not designed to do what you want it to do. It is a citation command (which you haven't used in your example), and has nothing to do with the bibliography.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is `cmsdate=both`, no macro needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{hume1739,
  author       = {David Hume},
  editor       = {David Fate Norton},
  title        = {A Treatise of Human Nature},
  publisher    = {Oxford University Press},
  year         = 2000,
  address      = {Oxford},
  options      = {cmsdate=both},
  origdate     = {1739/1740}
}
@article{mori2012uncanny,
    AUTHOR      = {Mori, Masahiro},
    TITLE       = {The Uncanny Valley},
    TRANSLATOR  = {MacDorman, Karl F. and Kageki, Norri},
    JOURNAL     = {IEEE Robotics \& Automation Magazine},
    VOLUME      = {19},
    NUMBER      = {2},
    PAGES       = {98--100},
    ORIGDATE    = {1994},
    OPTIONS     = {cmsdate=both},
    YEAR        = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

Book \autocite{hume1739} and article \autocite{mori2012uncanny}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]